# Is the utf-8 charset of Apache specified by "AddDefaultCharset utf-8", full utf-8 or not?

Tags: mysql, apache, unicode, utf-8

This is based on my observation that for mysql, the default character set utf8 is somewhat misleading it doesn’t support full Unicode as it cannot store four-byte UTF-8-encoded characters. It's actually utf8mb4 charset which is full Unicode (with variable width).

What is the situation with Apache? If I say "AddDefaultCharset utf-8", is it referring to full Unicode such as utf8mb4 for mysql, or is it referring to a watered down version of utf-8 such as mysql's utf8 which doesn't support the possible 4mb of space.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache doesn't care of the actual response body contents; when you specify

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

directive it just adds a corresponding `charset=utf-8` response header. That's it.

Comment: Surely that response header affects something though, else what is it's purpose? Also, what utf-8 charset is that response header referring to?

Comment: @user There's only one UTF-8 charset. MySQL with its non-UTF-8 utf8 is a sad exception. The header that's being set tells the browser what encoding the rest of the following content is in.

Comment: @user1796995: the header's purpose is to tell the client what encoding the body is encoded with. So - the data is served as is (it's your responsibility to generate it properly); and next it's a client's job to treat it properly (it's the client (browser?) developers' responsibility to handle it properly). No place for apache to fail.

Comment: @zerkms Ahh I think I've got it. So all apache is doing is telling the webclient this data is UTF-8, now you do your job and handle it correctly. So if I am using php, it is php which will have encoded the body with Utf-8? Not Apache. Apache is just *telling* the web client it's utf-8 and the web client (eg browser) has to handle this appropriately? Have I got it?